# How can I restore the old STM32 files to new

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, stm32cubeide, truestudio

There is a TrueStudio project which is written in 2014. How can I use this project? I can show main.c file on STM32IDE but IDE can not see headers and another files. All file locations are different. Is there a program for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way.

1. Create new project for your uC
2. Delete source files
3. Paste in the project explorer files from your old project:
   3.a in windows explorer copy the whole project tree to the clipboard
   3.b paste it into project explorer.